# The exact distribution of the conditional distribution of the OLS estimator

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, least-squares

This is the problem that I have tried figuring it out for a while, and I still need some advice because there is no explicit derivation in the textbook that I have seen so far. The problem looks easy to me at the first place, but, after pondering, it makes me feel uncertain. The issue is the derivation of exact distribution

Suppose I have **"the normal regression model"** like this.

$Y_{i}=\beta X_{i}+e_{i}$

Where $X_{i}$ and $Y_{i}$ are scalars and $e_{i}
|Xi  \sim   N(0, σ^2)$. This model makes the assumption
that **the conditional error distribution is exactly normal**.

My question: How can I derive the conditional distribution of the OLS estimator for $β$,
$ \beta^{OLS} |Xi ∼ . . . $ ?

If I have to derive **the exact distribution**, not the approximate one.
That is, I do not need to use asymptotic theory because of the normality assumption imposed on the error distribution.

Any suggestions, please?

Comment: given $X$, the estimator $\beta$ is linearly related to the error term $e$, so its distribution is Gaussian; the mean is the true value of $\beta$ and the variance is smaller than $\sigma^2$ by a factor $\sum_i X_i^2$.

Comment: Thank you @Carlo.   I have just realized that it is just about the exact finite sample property. First, I am a little bit confused with the large sample properties. (i.e. Asymptotic distribution) that involves the approximation one.